# Merge transactions of two tables

Tags: sql

[image: 1]

Thanks for your attention to answer the question.
You can understand this problem seeing Above image or
My Question is that I have table1 in which I am inserting Issue Items details and I have table2 in which I am inserting Receive Items details. There are two case which have to cover first case is - when I issue 3 items and receive 5 Items Or second case is - when I issue 10 Items I receive 4 item. Please help to give the solution for the same.

[image: 2]

I tried joins and union to solve this but did not resolve it.

Comment: Please provide the data in text form. Also, display what you want to achieve and the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please pay attention to some important points if you want to prevent your question will be closed without any useful answer: 1) Tag your DBMS, 2) Do not upload or link images, 3) Provide both sample input and expected outcome as tables, 4) Explain more detailed what you want to do, 5) Show what you tried so far and what exactly is not working as intended.  Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example